# wordpress content disappears when using if statement or switch/case

Tags: php, wordpress, str-replace, add-filter

When I created a function (in `child-theme/functions.php`) to modify text in `the_content()`, the following function worked well.

```
function my_text_changes ( $text ) {
    $text = str_replace( 'My Site Name', '<em>My Site Name</em>', $text );
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'the_content','my_text_changes' );
```

This function modifies only one portion of text (multiple times). When I changed the function so I could modify more portions of text, I took this same variable and str_replace and put it into a switch/case (also tried if statements) and all the content disappears.

```
function my_text_changes ( $text ) {

switch( $text ) { 

case "My Site Name":
    $text = str_replace( 'My Site Name', '<em>My Site Name</em>', $text );
    return $text;
break;
}
}
add_filter( 'the_content','my_text_changes' );
```

I want to build multiple cases but cannot get the first one to work. The same holds true if I change the switch/case to an if statement. I have tried changing `$text =` and the `return $text` to `$newtext =` and `return $newtext` to no avail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$text` argument that you are passing there contains the whole content. You `switch` assignment will never be true (unless the entirety of the content consists of *“My Site Name”*), and your text will not be substituted.

The reason why everything disappears is because you have to `return` the `$text` variable outside of the `switch` statement (or your `if/else`s) or else it will display nothing (basically you are substituting the entire content with nothing).

It is, in fact, sufficient that you run your `str_replace`s without any `if/else` or `switch`, if I understand your problem correctly.

### Edit:

While the original answer works, there is a better way. You argue in your comment that the second `$text` will overwrite the first assignment, which is true, but not a problem, since the previous one is already the text with the string correctly replaced. Just give it a try and see by yourself.

In any case, I checked the [docs for `str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and it does accept `array`s as arguments, so your problem may be solved like so:

```
function my_text_changes ( $text ) {
    $searches = array( 'My Site Name', 'a second string' );
    $replaces = array( '<em>My Site Name</em>', 'a <strong>second</strong> string' );
    $new_text = str_replace( $searches, $replaces, $text );
    /* ... */
    return $new_text;
}
```

#### Original answer

Just do:

```
function my_text_changes ( $text ) {
    $text = str_replace( 'My Site Name', '<em>My Site Name</em>', $text );
    $text = str_replace( 'second_string', 'replacement', $text);
    /* ... */
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: You have a good understanding of this situation. I understand `$text` contains the entire content. It is the haystack. Outside of an if statement or switch/case, the "needle" is found and replaced. However once you take the same code and put it into an if statement or switch/case, the haystack (content) disappears. 

Your recommendation overwrites the previous `$text` so that only the last var will execute.

Comment: Ha! Yes! I can see it. I will try it and am certain it will work. Thank you. The only down side to this solution, instead of an if or switch, is the array can grow pretty fast and keeping the search and replace arrays properly paired will be a chore. But at least, we can do it. Thanks for looking at this again.

Comment: Oh, wait a minute. Here is a problem. Let's say one of the search is for "A big drink of water" another is for "drink of water" and another is for "drink". Now, because each phrase has a different link, you need a hierarchy so that "drink" doesn't scoop the other two phrases, nor "drink of water" scoop "A big drink of water". This is where the if statement or switch/case come in. So, the problem still remains. If you have any thoughts, I would appreciate them. Nonetheless, thank you, again for working on this with me.

Comment: I'm not sure I entirely understand your problem. Can you make an edit to your original question with a real-world usecase scenario? Or else I'm stuck solving hypothetical examples that don't exactly line up with your problem.

Comment: The actual usage will be to highlight and link affiliate links. However, the usage is not limited to just the affiliate; it is divided among several products. That is why there must be a hiearchy, such as Product Name for First Product; Product Name for Shorter Version of Product and; Product Company Name, etc. Thank you for looking at this. I will get back to working on this, myself, in a couple days.

Comment: OK. Figured it out. Both your examples will work, if every link is split with the Company Name and the Product Name. See, the problem is linking the Company and Product together creates a conflict with statements linking only the Company Name because it will over-write the Company portion of the Company/Product link messing the anchor tag. However, if the statement grabs the Company and Product (necessary because several companies have similar products) but only links the Product. Then a statement creating a separate link for the Company will no longer conflict with Company and Product links.

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you for helping me think this through.

Comment: Here to help. Glad you figured it out. You should mark the question as solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use return statement before break.

But the issue seems to be different than the code cited. Can you check the php error logs on the hosting and share the same?

Comment: If you do not have the return before the break, there is no return. Also, there is no errors in the error log. Thank you, anyway.